# Munich My Way iPhone app, how can I make similar gallery?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I make a gallery like [the Munich My Way app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/munich-my-way/id372614236)?

I only want make the shoes view, with the transition from 1 shoe to other, the rest I am not interesting.

Are they using a `UIScrollView` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orus ,

Check https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary & check TKCoverflowview

this will help you to design gallery look

Comment: Wow!! That was fast, a lot of thanks for the answer :). I think this can help me, I'll try it.